# Facebook Graph API select wall status messages NOT from me

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can access all posts on my wall using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?fields=from,type&access_token=...
```

Actually I just need to select all posts from **others** on my wall so I don't need posts by **myself**. In the "selection" section of [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), it mentions the "q=" parameter to select based on contents. But neither of the following lines of code doesn't give me the answer:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?fields=from,type&q=!me()&access_token=...
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?fields=from,type&q<>me()&access_token=...
```

How can I only select posts from others on my wall?

Answer (score 1):

Just select them all, loop results and if you spot your post, unset that array.

Comment: that's what I'm already doing but it's not very efficient. I wonder if Graph API supprts a better way. In the old FQL mechanism, I assume it has the NOT operator from SQL but I don't know how to reach the same results with a Graph API URL query.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?fields=from,type&q<>me()&access_token=... can't work as <> isn't valid get operator...